# Using grunt to update base href

Tags: gruntjs

During the build process of an angular app, I would like to update the `<base href="/app-dev/">` tag to `<base href="/app/">` inside `index.html`

Is there a way to update this tag with `usemin` (for now, I use it to update the links to the js and css)? If not, what grunt task should I use to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I used grunt-processhtml too like so

in your say index.html file

```
<!-- build:[href]:build /path/you/want/ -->
<base href="/~myusername/myapp/public/" />
<!-- /build -->
```

in your Gruntfile.js add a task config like so

```
processhtml: {
    options: {
        //
    },
    build: {
        files: {
            'dist/index.html':['public/index.html']
        }
    }
}
```

and install the npm package of course!

```
npm install grunt-processhtml --save-dev
```