# Using grunt and processhtml to update base href (without preserving parts of the path)

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm trying to use Grunt and processhtml to update my `<base href="path">` in index.html. This adds on on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162992/using-grunt-to-update-base-href) which seems to be dead and not have an accepted answer. Also the answer there is not working for me.

The part in my index.html:

```
<!-- build:[href] /ndt/dist-local/ -->
<base href="/ndt/web/">
<!-- /build -->
```

What comes out is:

```
<base href="/ndt/dist-local/web">
```

What I want to come out is:

```
<base href="/ndt/dist-local/">
```

It adds on the web part (without the slash). How can I make it so that it doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work around `<!-- build:<attr> <target> -->` always including the last part, you can just use a combination of `remove`and `template`:

```
    <!-- build:remove -->
        <base href="/ndt/web/">
    <!-- /build -->

    <!-- build:template
        <base href="/ndt/dist-local/">
    /build -->
```

It's not the prettiest option, but it works. If you want to make it a bit more dynamic, you can include the dist-base as an `data`-option:

Gruntfile config:

```
{
  options: {
    data: {
      distbase: "/ndt/dist-local/
    }
  },
  files: /**/
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- build:remove -->
    <base href="/ndt/web/">
<!-- /build -->

<!-- build:template
    <base href="<%= distbase %>">
/build -->
```

Comment: This not only worked, it also solved another problem that I had, the fact that it needed to be something else for 2 different environments. Now I just add on another template block that responds to another environment et voila.